# Difference between "daily-live", "daily-preinstalled" & "daily"?

Tags: release-management

What are difference between "daily-live", "daily-preinstalled" & "daily" builds of Precise on http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [daily-live](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/):

> The desktop CD allows you to try Ubuntu without changing your computer at all, and at your option to install it permanently later. This type of CD is what most people will want to use.

- [daily](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/daily/current/):

> The alternate install CD allows you to perform certain specialist
>   installations of Ubuntu. It provides for the following situations:
>
> - setting up automated deployments;
> - upgrading from older installations without network access;
> - LVM and/or RAID partitioning;
> - installs on systems with less than about 384MiB of RAM (although note that low-memory - systems may not be able to run a full desktop
>     environment reasonably).

- [daily-preinstalled](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-preinstalled/current/):

> The preinstalled-desktop image allows you to unpack a preinstalled
>   version of Ubuntu onto a target device.
>
> There are five images available, each for a different type of
>   computer:
>
> - Texas Instruments OMAP3 preinstalled desktop image
> - Texas Instruments OMAP4 preinstalled desktop image
> - Freescale i.MX5x preinstalled desktop image
> - Texas Instruments OMAP3 (Hard-Float) preinstalled desktop image
> - Texas Instruments OMAP4 (Hard-Float) preinstalled desktop image

daily and daily-live are available in:

- PC (Intel x86)
- 64-bit PC (AMD64)
- 64-bit Mac (AMD64)
- Mac (PowerPC) and IBM-PPC (POWER5)

Comment: thanx for the answer. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Live is the usual Live cds you use, boot in to the desktop and then able to choose to Install.

Not sure about the other ones

Comment: I wish to catch a difference, but thanx, @friTTe

Comment: no worries hehe